# Angular + PrimeNg: issue with ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-template, primeng-turbotable

I want to create a new 'layer' between my templates and PrimeNg's TurboTable to use additional functions and features that I write, so I want to pass two `ng-template` to my own component, and from it to `p-table`, but it's not working.

In my `app.component.html`:

```
  <my-table>
    <ng-template #tableHeader pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Vin</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #tableBody pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
      <tr>
        <td>{{rowData.vin}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.color}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.year}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </my-table>
```

In `my-table.component.html`:

```
<p-table [value]="cars" sortField="brand" sortMode="single">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tableHeader" ></ng-template>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tableBody"></ng-template>
</p-table>
```

In `my-table.component.ts` I have these:

```
  @ContentChild('tableHeader')
  private tableHeader: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ContentChild('tableBody')
  private tableBody: TemplateRef<any>;
```

The error that I get:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'vin' of undefined.
```

Why `p-table` can't use `let-rowData` from `app.component.html`? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have de same problem and there is my solution:

1. In my-table.component.ts i used a QueryList to register all templates.

```
    @ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate)
    templates: QueryList<any>;
```

2. In my-table.component.html

```
    <p-table [value]="data">
            <ng-template let-item [pTemplate]="template.name" *ngFor="let template of templates">
              <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="template.template; context: { $implicit: item }"></ng-template>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

3. Finally my showcase looks like this:

```
    <hn-table [data]="cars">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th>Vin</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{item.vin}}</td>
                <td>{{item.year}}</td>
                <td>{{item.brand}}</td>
                <td>{{item.color}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
            summary!!
        </ng-template>
      </hn-table>
```

I'm sure there will be better solutions, but this is wath i found.
I hope this help you and someone help us to find a better solution.